# Django syncdb : "columname" cannot be cast to type integer

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to deploy my Django app, when developing I used the SQLite database. In production, I want to use a PostgreSQL database.

I just setup my project, copied the models, now I want to sync my db, when I use the following command:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/home/oras/webapps/leden_landing/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute return 
self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.ProgrammingError:
column "studierichting_id" cannot be cast to type integer
```

I don't understand how this can happen, does anybody know what I can do to solve this problem?

These are my models:

```
class Lid(models.Model):
    voornaam = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    achternaam = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    studienummer = models.IntegerField()
    studierichting = models.ForeignKey(Studie)

class Studie(models.Model):
    naam = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Since I don't have any data yet, and the database still needs to be setup, I don't understand how I can get this casting error...

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any migrations?

Comment: You don't need the `blank=False` attributes. All Django model fields are required by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it, like Visgean suggested, I still had some migrations. After I deleted the folder, the syncdb'ing could start :)